# check params required in php

Tags: php, arguments

is there a way to find out how many parameters/arguments does the function expect?

lets say

```
function foo($par,$bar=false){
   ...
}


//fictional function below
echo numbr_of_params('foo'); // should return 1// as $bar is optional :)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $reflection = new ReflectionFunction($function_name);
    $reflection->getNumberOfParameters();
    $reflection->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try function reflections: http://lv.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use the Reflection functions in PHP, such as [ReflectionFunction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php), especially [ReflectionFunction::getParameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters.php)